# Why inner classes allow static final fields?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

As per the [JLS section 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3),

> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is
>   explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant
>   variable

My question is WHY static final fields (constants) are allowed inside the inner classes ? The same question has been asked before as well but none of the answers explain the WHY part.

Comment: "The same question has been asked before" Please link to such a question.

Comment: "My question is WHY static final fields (constants) are allowed inside the inner classes" Even if you get an answer, what will it change? This is how it is designed; this was the design choice made. You can use this language feature, or not.

Comment: Probably to allow you to define static constants within the scope of your inner class? So, you put something into your inner class that only your inner class needs to know about ...

Comment: @ Andy Turner: Thanks for the quick response Andy. Even It would not change anything and yes it is upto the programmer to use a feature or not but don't you think we should know or atleast try to know the reasoning behind a particular deisgn ?

Comment: @Sumit it's not really worth asking why you *can* do something that explicitly stated in the specification, because the answer is simply that you can: it was either decided to be valuable enough or easy enough to include in the spec. The question (maybe) worth asking is why you would *want to* use it.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Actually the curiosity (atleast for me) to know WHY something is as the way it is, is worth asking the question. Anyways thanks for the reply.